# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Authorisation token Error on login screen

Tags: php, symfony, authorization, fosuserbundle

I'm going gcrazy!

I have just integrated FOSUserBundle into my Symfony2 project and am now getting an error on the login screen.

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The security context     contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at line 8.

My Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
            #entity: {class Smada\Agenda7Bundle\Entity\User, property: username}

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    false
        #        secured_area:
        #              pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        #              form_login:
        #                  check_path: _security_check
        #                  login_path: _demo_login
        #              logout:
        #                  path:   _demo_logout
        #                  target: _demo

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And my config.yml has this in it

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Smada\Agenda7\Entity\User
```

Does anyone know what my issue is?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IMO you have 2 rules for /login url

Please remove:

```
firewalls:
    # ...
    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false
```

Comment: Thanks though it didn't seem to make a difference. I just removed FOSUser bundle and reinstalled, seems to work now

Comment: @Adam and you kept login firewall as well?